# C# Query an excel fastest method

Tags: c#, sql, database, excel, oledb

I have an excel file and i am querying this on my C# program with SQL using OleDB.
But i faced with a problem. My file has about 300K rows and querying takes too much long time. I have googled for this issue and used some libraries such as spreadsheetlight and EPPlus but they haven't got query feature. 
Can anyone advice me for the fastest way to querying my file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what code you tried that was taking too long to process?

Comment: @downvoters, this is a legitimate question from OP! If you ever worked with 300-400K rows Excel files using OleDB you would know. There is no even need for code. It will be SLOW at least when a statement like this is executed: `"SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "$]";`

Comment: Query is very simple actually.
OleDbCommand date = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ["+date+"] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE ["+key+"]= " + array[i].ToString(), connection);

Comment: @andrews yes it is slow and i mentioned before. Can you give me an advice to speed up querying file?

Comment: Why won't EPPlus work? What do you mean by "query" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with 400-800K rows Excel files. The task was to read all rows and insert them into SQL Server DB. From my experience OleDB was not able to process such big files in a timely manner, therefore we had to fall back to Excel file import directly into DB using SQL Server means, e.g. [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

Even smaller files, like 260K rows took approx. an hour with OleDB to import row-by-row into DB table using Core2 Duo generation hardware.

So, in your case you can consider the following:

1.Try reading Excel file in chunks using ranged `SELECT`:

```
OleDbCommand date = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ["+date+"] FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z10000]
                                  WHERE ["+key+"]= " + array[i].ToString(), connection);
```

Note, `[Sheet1$A1:Z10000]` tells OleDB to process only first 10K rows of columns A to Z of the sheet instead the whole sheet. You can use this approach if for example your Excel file is sorted and you know that you don't need to check ALL rows but only for this year. Or you can change `Z10000` dynamically to read the next chunk of the file and combine result with the previous one.

2.Get all your Excel file contents directly into DB using direct DB import, such as mentioned `OPENROWSET` of the MS SQL Server and then run your search queries against RDBMS instead of the Excel files.

I would personally suggest option #2. Comment if you can use DB at all and what RDBMS product/version is available to you, if any.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am very thankful for your answer. Here is details. I am working on a thesis about patients who went to hospital again in 3 days and researching for reasons. I have hospital records of a year includes patients arrival date to hospital and file has 300K rows. First i group by patientID.Then in a for loop i called select query for every single patient id like this; "select date from sheet1 where patientID = myarray[i] ". (as i mentioned on comment.) By this way i fetch all arrival dates for every single patient, i check , if day<3 i take it. I have no information about mssql unf. @andrews

Comment: @FK if this is a one time activity, your best solution would be to get data in DB first and then user SQL to query it. Otherwise it will be a pain. Have you ever worked with Relation Database Management Systems before, MySQL, PostregSQL, SQL Server? Any of those would work for you.

Comment: I have worked with mysql before. I guess i am going to export all the data to mysql database. How can i export excel to mysql?

Comment: @FK search google or StackOverflow on how to import Excel into MySQL, there are many samples. If you periodically receive new file with visits, then you can set up a nightly process to import all data into mysql and then during daytime you can run your SQL queries. If this answer has helped you, make sure you mark it as accepted, unfortunately, you cannot vote because of low rep.

Comment: @FK you're welcome! I've already voted up your question before posting the answer. If you have troubles getting your Excel data into MySQL, post another question with proper tags, but be sure to include your actual code to show what you have tried to keep the down-voters away.

Comment: I am trying to read excel chunk by chunk. first [Sheet1$A1:Z1000] is succesfull but [Sheet1$A10001:Z20000] gives OleDbException :(